# JUnit Rule TemporaryFolder

Tags: java, junit, junit-rule

I'm creating a `TemporaryFolder` using the `@Rule` annotation in JUnit 4.7. I've tried to create a new folder that is a child of the temp folder using `tempFolder.newFolder("someFolder")` in the `@Before` (setup) method of my test. It seems as though the temporary folder gets initialized after the setup method runs, meaning I can't use the temporary folder in the setup method. Is this correct (and predictable) behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a problem in Junit 4.7. If you upgrade a newer Junit (for example 4.8.1) all @Rule will have been run when you enter the @Before method:s. A related bug report is this: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/issues/79

Comment: I would not that even with JUnit 4.8.2 that on Windows 7 the TemporaryFolder rule doesn't work correctly.
Looks like it's a permissions issue.

Comment: link is broken; working one: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/issues/79

Answer (score 6):

This works as well.  **EDIT** if in the @Before method it looks like myfolder.create() needs called.  And this is probably bad practice since the javadoc says not to call TemporaryFolder.create().  **2nd Edit** Looks like you have to call the method to create the temp directories if you don't want them in the @Test methods.  Also make sure you close any files you open in the temp directory or they won't be automatically deleted.

```
<imports excluded>

public class MyTest {

  @Rule
  public TemporaryFolder myfolder = new TemporaryFolder();

  private File otherFolder;
  private File normalFolder;
  private File file;

  public void createDirs() throws Exception {
    File tempFolder = myfolder.newFolder("folder");
    File normalFolder = new File(tempFolder, "normal");
    normalFolder.mkdir();
    File file = new File(normalFolder, "file.txt");

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file);
    out.println("hello world");
    out.flush();
    out.close();
  }

  @Test
  public void testSomething() {
    createDirs();
    ....
  }
}
```

Comment: While this does create a new folder, tempFolder is not actually in a temp location (it is in your working directory) because myFolder has not been set to a temporary location. It will not get cleaned up either.

Comment: This leaves the directories in the $TEMP or %TEMP% directory so still looking for real answer.